# How to remove or disable a target in cmake

Tags: cmake

My project uses a third party library project. This third party library comes with their own cmake project file and we use it. The problem is that their cmake project has lots of test and sample executable targets, and after we include that cmake our final cmake-generated xcode project has all these irrelevant test and sample executable targets.
Obvious approach is to modify that cmake file and remove/comment out all these test and sample executable targets. However, this won't work well when we update the library. What alternatives do I have, is there a way to include a cmake file and then disable/remove some of the targets that the cmake file declares?

Comment: Without more details, I don't know if the target property [EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL.html) could be useful for your irrelevant test and sample targets. Another option would be to avoid including the 3rd party cmake project, and using `find_package()` to import only the relevant targets of the 3rd party lib. Of course, I don't know if this is applicable in your case.

Comment: does this third party use CTest ? in this case you mau use `ENABLE_TESTING` or does it have some option to disable samples ?

Comment: @Mizux No, it's not related to CTest in any way. The library uses [abseil](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp) and if I include it's CMakeLists.txt I end up with 50+ targets added to my project, whereas I only need like 5 of them

Comment: There is a [document](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/blob/master/CMake/README.md) explaining how to integrate that library in your own projects and how to disable unit tests, which seems to be `BUILD_TESTING=OFF`

Comment: @Pedro I saw it, the doc is useless. If you add_directory with abseil you'll get 50 targets added to your VS solution. `BUILD_TESTING=OFF` will remove tiny portion of these. The point of the question: if a 3rd party cmake file declares gazilion targets and I include it because I want to link to a single target from that 3rd party cmake, how can I do it, so that my final VS solution doesn't have all these irrelevant gazillion targets (obviously without editing 3rd party cmake file)

Comment: what's the actual problem you're facing with those targets? are they using names for targets that you'd like to use? In that case, look into installing the third party library to the binary dir and import it from there so only the namespaced versions of the target names are occupied. You can automate this with `ExternalProject`. Are the targets being built when you build all targets in your project? Use `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` with your call to `add_subdirectory`.

Comment: note that there's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69630202/11107541) that deals with a situation where the definition of the project is not just an inconvenience, but causes the buildsystem configuration to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that the third-party library behind the unit tests and example code you wish to disable/remove is abseil.

Abseil's docs have a very clear and thorough documentation on how to disable abseil's unit tests and example code. See [Abseil's README section on Running Abseil Tests with CMake](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/blob/master/CMake/README.md#running-abseil-tests-with-cmake).  It is pretty clear on how abseil's unit tests are only enabled if both `BUILD_TESTING` and `ABSL_BUILD_TESTING` are enabled.

After checking the abseil's CMakeLists.txt, it's also clear that you also need to explicitly disable `ABSL_BUILD_TEST_HELPERS`. See [here](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/blob/065d50d9f835cce8e4ee8f6d595518c409669901/CMakeLists.txt#L152).

Typically, you'll have to enable `BUILD_TESTING` in your projects if you expect to use CTest to run your project's own unit tests, as it's enabled by default once you include CTest ([source](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CTest.html)).  However, abseil's CMakeLists.txt is clear that you need to explicitly disable `ABSL_BUILD_TESTING` and `ABSL_BUILD_TEST_HELPERS` to to disable its unit tests.