# How to prevent cmake to not add all targets from external dependencies using modern cmake constructs

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen

I am trying to add external dependencies to my new cmake project in the cleanest and modern cmake way possible.
I want to download these dependencies during configuration time. My problem is that all the targets from external dependencies are always imported. This spams my configurations in e.g. Clion which i want to be much cleaner by default but as you can see i have several useless targets from gtest, googlebenchmark, eigen and spdlog in the figure below. The project should compile on Windows and Linux.

[image]

So my question is how to prevent this?

I watched several modern cmake videos, e.g.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eC9-iRN2b04 and the sources from https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/.

My project folder structure looks as follows

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── Ikarus
|   └── CMakeLists.txt
|   └── addexternalLibs.cmake
│   └── src
│       └── Ikarus
│           └── [...]
├── problems
|   └── CMakeLists.txt
|   └── [.cpp files]
├── tests
|   └── CMakeLists.txt
|   └── [.cpp files]
├── benchmarks
|   └── CMakeLists.txt
|   └── [.cpp files]
```

I have a top level `CMakeLists.txt` as follows

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(Ikarus)

add_subdirectory(Ikarus)
add_subdirectory(problems)
add_subdirectory(tests)
add_subdirectory(benchmarks)
```

In the folder `Ikarus` i want to build my `Ikarus_lib` which should be used by the targets defined in `problems`, `tests` and `benchmarks`.

The file `Ikarus/CMakeLists.txt` looks as follows

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE IKARUS_CPP_SOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} CONFIGURE_DEPENDS  *.cpp )


add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_lib STATIC)
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME}_lib PRIVATE ${IKARUS_CPP_SOURCES})

include(addexternalLibs.cmake)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}_lib PUBLIC src)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_lib PUBLIC Eigen3::Eigen
                                          PUBLIC spdlog::spdlog)
```

Now i want to talk about the contents of  the file `Ikarus/addexternalLibs.cmake` where the external depencies are imported. The difficulties similar arise in benchmark and tests where i import googletest and googlebenchmark but i think i will restrict myself to the Ikarus_lib case since the difficulties are the same.

Since i want to download my dependencies during configuration time i found the nice solution using https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html

The result is `Ikarus/addexternalLibs.cmake`:

```
include(FetchContent)

message("Configure Eigen: ")

FetchContent_Declare(
        eigen
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen.git
        GIT_TAG 3.4
        GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
        GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)
option(EIGEN_BUILD_DOC OFF)
option(BUILD_TESTING OFF)
option(EIGEN_LEAVE_TEST_IN_ALL_TARGET OFF)
option(EIGEN_BUILD_PKGCONFIG OFF)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(eigen)

message("====================================")
message("Configure spdlog: ")

FetchContent_Declare(
        spdlog
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/gabime/spdlog.git
        GIT_TAG v1.8.5
        GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
        GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)
option(SPDLOG_BUILD_SHARED OFF)
option(SPDLOG_BUILD_ALL OFF)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(spdlog)
```

This solution works and i managed to deactivate some targets using the options `EIGEN_BUILD_DOC OFF...`. But still i have lots of different useless targets as seen in the image above which cannot be deactivated using options of the package.

I tried several other things, e.g. using `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL.html as follows

```
FetchContent_Declare(
        eigen
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen.git
        GIT_TAG 3.4
        GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
        GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)
option(EIGEN_BUILD_DOC OFF)
option(BUILD_TESTING OFF)
option(EIGEN_LEAVE_TEST_IN_ALL_TARGET OFF)
option(EIGEN_BUILD_PKGCONFIG OFF)

FetchContent_GetProperties(eigen)
if(NOT eigen_POPULATED)
   FetchContent_Populate(Eigen)
    add_subdirectory(${eigen_SOURCE_DIR} ${eigen_BINARY_DIR} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
endif()
```

which also works but does also adds all that targets which i don't want. Therefore, `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` does not work the way i think it works.

Another way of using `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` could be

```
include(FetchContent)

message("Configure Eigen: ")

FetchContent_Declare(
        eigen
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen.git
        GIT_TAG 3.4
        GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
        GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)
option(EIGEN_BUILD_DOC OFF)
option(BUILD_TESTING OFF)
option(EIGEN_LEAVE_TEST_IN_ALL_TARGET OFF)
option(EIGEN_BUILD_PKGCONFIG OFF)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(eigen)
set_target_properties(eigen PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE)
```

which also does not change the behaviour.

I also tried `CPMAddPackage` from https://github.com/cpm-cmake/CPM.cmake

```
CPMAddPackage(
        GITLAB_REPOSITORY libeigen/eigen
        GIT_TAG 3.4
        OPTIONS "EIGEN_BUILD_DOC NO"
                "BUILD_TESTING NO"
                "EIGEN_LEAVE_TEST_IN_ALL_TARGET YES"
                "EIGEN_BUILD_PKGCONFIG NO"
)
```

which also works but also adds all that targets.

So now i don't know what else to try and i think i will just keep the targets and delete them from my Clion configuration interface and hope they don't reappear. But still i want to understand what am i missing. I think this is a common problem and the solution should be very easy?

Furthermore, i know that i can just download e.g. eigen and use `include_directories(...)` to automatically add the headers without the targets. But on one hand this is not modern cmake as advertised in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eC9-iRN2b04 where using `include_directories` is called an anti-pattern and one should "think in modules". On the other hand this does not help for packages which are not header-only.

So how can this problem be solved elegantly? Additionally, i would appreciate every other comment to my (bad) usage of Cmake. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue with google benchmark.

Comment: Nope but i  have the same problem again now. And ended up in my own question here.

Comment: This seems very similar to [How to remove or disable a target in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60127243/11107541). Have you seen that (unanswered) thread? This looks kind of like a duplicate to me (albeit written much more clearly).

Comment: I haven't used CLion (I use VS Code). could you elaborate on what you mean by "spams my configurations"? On VS Code there's support for CMake presets where you can define build presets and set default targets to build. I wonder if there's similar functionality in CLion and whether that would mitigate whatever is bothering you.